# Is there a way in Rails to implement an image_tag type mouseover for just text? JavaScript & CSS solutions not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails

Basic Problem: I have a line of text, and on hover, I want that text to change to something else. Basic, right? What's tripping me up is that the text in question is stored in a hash in my controller, and I'm looping through it.

Here's a smaller version of my hash in my PagesController:

```
def team_list
    return [ {
        name: "Employee 1",
        title: "Founder and CEO",
        secret_title: "Something Funny",
        image: "about-employee-color.jpg",
        alt_image: "about-employee-alt.jpg"
      },
      {
        name: "Employee 2",
        title: "Not Founder and CEO",
        secret_title: "Something Else Funny",
        image: "about-employee2-color.jpg",
        alt_image: "about-employee2-alt.jpg"
      } ]
end
```

So then in my view (with @team defined as that hash in my PagesController), I'm looping through to create an About Page entry for each person.

```
    <% @team.each do |member| %>
    <div class="about-team">
      <%= image_tag member[:image], :mouseover => member[:baby_pic] %>
      <%= image_tag member[:baby_pic], :style => "display:none;" %>
      <h2><%= member[:name] %></h2>
      <h4><%= member[:title] %></h4>
      <h4 style="display:none;"><%= member[:secret_title] %></h4>
    </div>
    <% end %>
```

And I'm trying to see if there's an easy solution just like my image_tag :mouseover to get my titles to change to secret_titles on hover. I tried CSS first, similar to this. But I can't just put that member variable into the CSS since it doesn't exist outside that loop. I imagine JavaScript would be the same way.

```
    h4:hover { content:<%= member[:secret_title] %>; }
```

Anyway, what I'm hoping for is something like a text_tag that I haven't come across yet that has a similar :mouseover attribute as image_tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a JQuery functionality to swap values that you store directly as attributes in the DOM element, which in this case will be the `div` with class `about-team`, without really changing rails controller.

Storing values:

```
<% @team.each do |member| %>
<div class="about-team" member-title="<%= member[:title] %>" secret-title="<%= member[:secret_title] %>">
  <%= image_tag member[:image], :mouseover => member[:baby_pic] %>
  <%= image_tag member[:baby_pic], :style => "display:none;" %>
  <h2><%= member[:name] %></h2>
  <h4><%= member[:title] %></h4>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Swaping values (JQuery defined once):

```
    $('.about-team h4').hover(
      function(){     //mouse enter
          $(this).html($(this).parent().attr('secret-title'));
      },    
      function(){     //mouse leave
          $(this).html($(this).parent().attr('member-title'));        
      }    
    );
```

JQuery `hover` event as defined in API docs binds 2 handlers to the matched elements, so you can execute your swap logic when mouse is over and out as done in the code above.

**JSFIDDLE**: http://jsfiddle.net/VmqB7/4/

Comment: I'm still having the problem that initially led me away from this solution, which was that when they're all displayed together on a page, it swaps out ALL the h4 elements at a time. Here's a fiddle for what's happening: http://jsfiddle.net/VmqB7/2/

Comment: @LizHubertz i fixed the answer, the selector must be set the element hovered, `this`. On another note each `h2` and `h4` must be in new div's `class=about-team` so you have the `title` and `secret-title` accordingly to each member